# Enable USB OTG for a Galaxy Tab 4 7.0 SM-T230NU

Tags: usb

I want to be able to use a OTG cable on my Galaxy Tab 4 7.0. This tablet is not enabled for this feature. I am told it is missed the S3C Host file/apk, to do this. I can't seem to be able to get this done. Is it even possible, or should I just give up?

Answer (score 0):

This tablet does not support OTG.  I gave up and bought a Nexus 7 (2013)